# How do i program a Double hash implementation meant for strings?

Tags: c++, string-hashing, double-hashing

Hello everyone first time here but i'd like to start by first asking if my understanding of double hashing is correct.

Double hashing works by first implementing a hash function then checking to see if that spot is open. if the current spot is not open then using a second hash function determine another spot and then multiply it by the current attempt and then add it to the index spot that was determined by the first hashing algorithm.

the current code i'd have is:

```
unsigned int findPos(hashedObj& x)
{
    int offset = 1;
    int iteration = 0;
    unsigned int originalPos = myhash1( x );
    unsigned int index = originalPos;
    unsigned int secondPos = myhash2( x );
    while( array[ index ].info != EMPTY && array[ index ].element != x )
    {
        iteration = offset++ * secondPos;
        if ( ( originalPos + iteration ) > array.size( ) )
            index = ( originalPos + iteration ) % array.size( );
        else
            index = originalPos + iteration;
    }
    return ( index );
}

unsigned int hash1( const string& key, const int Tsize )
{
    //start the hashvalue at 0
    unsigned int hashVal = 0;

    //cout<<" the size of the table is: "<< Tsize <<endl;

    //add the ascii value for every word to hashval, multiply by 37 each time
    for ( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ )
        hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key[ i ];
    //mod hashval so it remains smaller than the table size
    hashVal %= Tsize;

    //return the itemes index value
    return hashVal;
}
```

i just realized i didnt include my second hash function

```
unsigned int hash2( const string& key, const int Tsize )
{
//store the sum of ascii numerical values
int hashVal = 0;

//add the values of all chars while multiplying each one with a prime number
for ( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ )
    hashVal = 29 * hashVal + key[ i ];

//mod the hashed value with a prime smaller than the table size, subtract that number
//with the prime just used and return that value
unsigned int index = 44497 - ( hashVal % 44497 );

return index;
}
```

it may not look like it but in the real deal tsize is being called correctly.

Comment: Side Note: You may want to mod your hash value in the computation loop rather than a single mod outside it. I.e. `hashVal = (37 * hashVal + key[ i ]) % Tsize;` This can avoid an overflow in a potentially long string.

Comment: i did do that right before i return the number

Comment: The problem is that if you hash War & Peace using this function you might run out of bits before you ever get to the mod.

Comment: i think i see what you guys are saying i had never thought that it could happen since it is a unsigned int. i was just about to comment on how i am using this to hash a unix dictionary file but keep running into seg faults for unknown reasons i did what you both suggested and now it's gone. i cant up vote you guys cause it wont let me but u guys are awesome

Comment: In case you were wondering why it just works to do what I describe, consider the chaining property of [modulo arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). `(a*b)%c = ((a%c)*(b%c))%c`. It is also worth noting (hopefully obviously) that `(a * (b%c))%c` is equally viable. Anyway, just chain them like I showed you in my first comment and don't worry about it after that =P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is incorrect:

```
if ( ( originalPos + iteration ) > array.size( ) )
    index = ( originalPos + iteration ) % array.size( );
else
    index = originalPos + iteration;
}
```

Should be:

```
if ( ( originalPos + iteration ) >= array.size( ) )
    index = ( originalPos + iteration ) % array.size( );
else
    index = originalPos + iteration;
}
```

or better yet, since you're wasting more than the % op by doing the if, and the answer is the same regardless, you can just get rid of the if altogether:

```
index = ( originalPos + iteration ) % array.size( );
```

Comment: oh right i forgot that we start counting from 0 and not from one.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could completely simplify it by saying

```
unsigned int hashkey = myhash1( x );
unsigned int stepSz = myhash2( x );
while( array[ index ].info != EMPTY && array[ index ].element != x )
        hashKey = (hashKey + stepSz) % capacity;
return hashkey;
```

Which accomplishes the same thing while making the while loop a lot smaller (and getting rid of the extra variable). I'm assuming you don't want to allow duplicates (hence the second condition in the while loop?).